# How can I compare a slice to a byte string literal?

Tags: rust

I have a method that tried to match a slice of [u8] to a number of byte string literals:

```
pub(crate) fn from_slice(slice: &[u8]) -> Option<SqlStateCode> {
    match slice {
      b"3030303030" => Some(SqlStateCode::SuccessfulCompletion),
      b"3031303030" => Some(SqlStateCode::Warning),
      b"3031303043" => Some(SqlStateCode::DynamicResultSetsReturned),
      _=> None
    }
}
```

Except it won't work unless I replace the byte string literal with an array:

```
[30, 31, 30, 30, 43] => Some(SqlStateCode::DynamicResultSetsReturned)
```

Is there a way to make this work with the literal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your byte string literals are incorrect; the byte sting literal `b"3031303043"` does not correspond to the slice `[30, 31, 30, 30, 43]` but rather to the slice `[51, 48, 51, 49, 51, 48, 51, 48, 52, 51]`.

This is because each character in the literal is replaced with its ASCII value in the slice.

The corresponding byte string literal for `[30, 31, 30, 30, 43]` using hex escape sequences for the control characters would be `b"\x1E\x1F\x1E\x1E+"`.

Comment: for correctness, isn't it the uft8 value rather than ASCII?

Comment: no, byte strings are ascii not utf-8 https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#byte-string-literals

Comment: every utf-8 sequence is a byte sequence, but not every byte sequence is a utf-8 sequence